# using Regex to match something from left

Tags: regex

```
Train from London to Boston - match
Train from Boston to London
Train from Cardif to London
Bus from London to Paris - match
```

How can I match if London appear before any other cities with regex? I can do it with string matching with loop in JavaScript but I think regex is better.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is extremely straightforward, but you don't appear to have made any effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @EdCottrell I don't know bout regex.

Comment: Why would you switch to regex? Why do you think it better?

Comment: @qxg one line of code

Comment: @Jennifer Okay, but this is not a site where we teach you how to code without you making any effort first. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). You're expected to make at least some effort to solve a problem before asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get lines which includes `London to`

```js
var str = `Train from London to Boston - match
Train from Boston to London
Train from Cardif to London
Bus from London to Paris - match`,
  city = 'london';

console.log(
  str.match(new RegExp('^.*\\b' + city + '\\sto\\b.*$', 'gmi'))
)
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/wF8yT5/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: what if London is a variable in javascript?

Comment: @Jennifer : it's regex pattern

Comment: Yup I know but what if London is a variable? It should be dynamic, shouldn't hardcode london in regex.

Comment: What if I have multiple language? `to` is english, how do `a` which means `to` in spanish.

Comment: @Jennifer : use `(to|a)` , eg `new RegExp('^.*\\b' + city + '\\s(to|a)\\b.*$', 'gmi')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\bLondon(?=\s*to\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC8kK3/1)

**Explanation:**
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`(?=…)`: Positive lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/cV6wG7/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)

Javascript

```
var re = /\bLondon(?=\s*to\b)/g; 
var str = 'Train from London to Boston - match\nTrain from Boston to London\nTrain from Cardif to London\nBus from London to Paris - match';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: `\b` is for? how to use this with javascript?

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary, you can use `\sLondon(?=\s*to\s)` for same result.